Angular, when i scroll on body my select is closing
I have a select tag with options, problem is that when i open this select and scroll with my body scroll select is closing, how i can prevent this action? or like don't let the select to close when i scroll with my body scroll

Could you please check if defining ScrollStrategy using injection token MAT_SELECT_SCROLL_STRATEGY helps you?

@itan mare Please check this issue in this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts
